# cpanel IP block not working Magento Multistore

Tags: magento2, cpanel

We use cpanel IP blocker function to block some IP's. However we have a Magento 2.2.6 multistore setup with for every store a folder with it's own .htaccess.

Now cpanel only blocks in public_html.

When we try to copy the IP's then that site give a server misconfiguration.
Weird as the . htaccess is exactly the same.

Anybody any solution on an effective way to block visitor IP's on a Magento 2 multistore setup? Thank you.